# Definition of $H$-field with Magnetization

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, dipole

i am trying to understand the H-field more intuitively. My textbook defines the H-field as follows: 
$\vec{B} = \mu_0 (\vec{H}+\vec{M}) $, where $\vec{M}=\frac{\sum_i{p_i}}{V}$ is the magnetic dipole moment per Volume. The author says that this is similar to the the electric displacement and Polarization $\vec{E}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} (\vec{D}-\vec{P})$ and states that $\mu_0\vec{H}$ is the vakuum magnetic field.

I think this implies that  $\vec{M}$ has to be the magnetic field produced by the induced dipoles, similar to $\frac{\vec{P}}{\epsilon_0}=\frac{\rho_b}{\epsilon_0} \hat{x}$ being equal to the field of 2 plates with the charge density $\rho_b$ of the bound charges.

Now i tried to calculate the average field of those dipoles in the volume and add it to the field induced by the dipoles outside of the volume and see if it equals to the magnetization, but i couldnt come up with a solution and it seems kind of a complicated thing to do for me.

Does anyone have a simpler explanation why this analogy holds or could do the averaging for me?